# How to specify minlength in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

If the status value is completed then comment field is required is working good.But the problem is, I want to specify comment field is required for minimum of 50 character.

**The Below code:** index.php

```
   <!-- Select Basic -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Status</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="status" name="status[]" class="form-control" >
          <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
          <option value="Work in process">Work in process</option>
          <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Comment</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="commentss" name="comment[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" /> 
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-24">
    <div class="input_fields" style="color:black">
         <button class="add_field btn " onclick="incrementValue()" >Add More</button>
         <div>
         <input type="text" name="mytextt[]" hidden="" ></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#status").click(function () {

            if ($("#status").val() == "Completed") {
                $("#commentss").attr("required", "required");
            }
            else
              $("#commentss").attr("required", false);
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `length` to find the length of the string

```
if($('#commentss').val().length < 50){
  alert("Please enter 50 characters atleast");
} else {
  //submit
}
```

Comment: This function is not working .it is just displaying the alert message if i keep the comment field empty and click save .it store the data without validation@Thamaraiselvam

Comment: @aiffin this is just a POC , you need to change the code according to your need

Answer (score 1):

For this please use below code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#status").click(function () {

        var commenttext = document.getElementById('commentss').value;
        if (commenttext.length < 50)
        {
         alert("Please Enter minimum 50 character!")
        }
        else
        {
        //Add code
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery ...

**For Dynamic Tracking ...** 
  (You can use blur or keyup even too.)

```
 $(function() {
        //disable submit if you want to
        $('#commentss').on('input', function(e) {
            if(this.value.length >= 50) {
                //success
            } else {
                //fail?
            }
        });
    });
```

**To Validate on Click only ...**

Go with the answer of Thamaraiselvam.